# What causes GA goal completions to disappear?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, gtag.js

I have a site that uses google analytics to track events and goal completions.  I am using gtag.

Twice now I have had goal completions from the previous day reset to 0 and I have no idea what is causing this behavior.

For example, when I looked at GA Monday evening I saw over 90 goal completions.  On Tuesday morning I still saw over 90 goal completions recorded for Monday.  By late Tuesday afternoon the goal completions recorded for Monday were at 0.  All of the events that are tied to goals are still in google analytics.

The days surrounding Monday (Sunday and Tuesday) have kept their goals and look okay.  This also occured once last week (on Thursday) with the goals being reset to zero but the days around it being okay.

I have not changed anything in GA or in my code.

What would cause goal completions to be counted by GA but then to go missing/reset to zero?  I've never seen this behavior before.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: . Le sigh... How are you absolutely certain this isn't an implementation issue and not programming related?

Comment: if its code related you should include a [example] showing what your doing and describing any issues with your solution.   if your having issues with how events are tracked in GA thats a GA question, or an analytics understanding question neither of which are programing related.

Comment: If its not a bug on your end and you are receiving most (but not all) goal completions than I think it's because of people who block google analytics tracking.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug, I have received other reports on this recent problem and there is no logical explanation. I hope Google will let us know something soon.